# Implementation of C in JNI , syntax changing

Tags: c, java-native-interface

One thing that confused me from JNI tutorial website is the changing of  C syntax. Do I have to rewrite this

```
/* helloworld without JNI implementation */

  #include <stdio.h>

  void main()
  {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return;
  }
```

into this

```
/* JNI implementation - HelloJNI.c */

#include "HelloWorld.h"
#include "jni.h"
#include  "stdio.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  return;
}
```

for every JNI implementation of C ?
Because from my understanding, if the answer is yes, i need to rewrite 100 methods if there's 100 methods in a .c file which seems wrong.

thanks for answering and sorry for noobies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JNI interface stuff is only needed on the boundary between Java and C.

So, even if you have a *thousand* functions, if you're only calling two of those via JNI directly (with the others being called by those two, or called by other functions that those two call, and so on), *they're* the only two you need to change.

In other words, you can do something like:

```
/* C implementation - HelloJNI.c */

#include "HelloWorld.h"
#include "jni.h"
#include  "stdio.h"

// Normal C function, not called directly from Java.

static void output (char *str) {
  printf ("%s", str);
}

// JNI C function, called from Java.

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
  output("Hello world\n");
  return;
}
```